# Set Items order Inflate menu android

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a 4 buttons menu in my app, I have troubles to set an order in the menu buttons, I would like have first Share, Refresh in the top 2 colum and About and Exit in the bottom 2 colum.

I need to set an order:
NOW -> 1.- About, 2.- Refresh, 3.- Share and 4.- Exit,

DESIRED -> 1.- Share, 2.- refresh, 3.- About, and 4.- Exit

[image]

MENU XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:title="@string/share"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_button"
    android:title="@string/exit"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
    android:title="@string/about"/>
```

MENU ACTIVITY

```
public boolean handleMenuSelect(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.share:
        String shareBody = "Conoce tu horoscopo diario "
                + activity.getString(R.string.app_name) + ", "
                + activity.getString(R.string.share_url);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent
                .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                "Share via"));
        return true;

    case R.id.refresh:
        Intent refresh = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(refresh);

        return true;


    case R.id.about:
        String appVersion = activity.getString(R.string.about);
        PackageInfo pInfo;
        try {
            pInfo = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    activity.getPackageName(), 0);
            appVersion = pInfo.versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO: logging
        }

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogAboutClickListener = new Aboutlistener();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(
                activity.getString(R.string.about_text) + appVersion)
                .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok),
                        dialogAboutClickListener).show();
        return true;


    case R.id.exit:
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogYesNoClickListener = new Exitlistener(
                activity);

        AlertDialog.Builder builderYesNo = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builderYesNo
                .setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.are_you_sure))
                .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.yes),
                        dialogYesNoClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.no),
                        dialogYesNoClickListener).show();

        return true;


    default:
        return activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Mainactivity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem share = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    share.setEnabled(true);

    MenuItem refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
    refresh.setEnabled(true);

    MenuItem about = menu.findItem(R.id.about);
    about.setEnabled(true);

    MenuItem exit = menu.findItem(R.id.exit);
    exit.setEnabled(true);
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return new Mainmenu(this).handleMenuSelect(item);
}
```

Comment: You haven't described the problem or asked a question.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what is happening, and one of what you want to happen?  A picture made using Paint is just fine.

Comment: I need to set an order, Now I have 1.- About, 2.- Refresh, 3.- Share and 4.- Exit, I need 1.- Share, 2.- refresh, 3.- About, and 4.- Exit

Comment: At first glance it should work as you expect. Could you please close and open Eclipse and then select Project/Clean? Sometimes strange errors are related with bad xml interpretation which disappears after cleaning the project....